# tabular vertical alignment with hyperref TextField

Tags: tables, hyperref, textfield

I'm using a TextField within a tabular environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{29em}r}
\TextField[name=W,multiline=true,width=\linewidth,height=3\baselineskip]{} %
 &(2)\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: bottom aligned text]

I would like for the "(2)" to be aligned to the top of the cell, rather than the bottom. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `adjustbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{29em}r}
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\TextField[name=W,multiline=true,width=\linewidth,height=3\baselineskip]{}} %
 &(2)\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```